# what is the usage of redirect URI of native client and redirect url of a web app in azure b2c?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

Does a redirect URI of native client means that which endpoint of azure b2c the native client will be send to get the jwt from azure b2c? [image]

Does a redirect url of a web app is means that which endpoint of my webapp the browser will be send to? DoesThe azure b2c will give a jwt to the web browser, and then redirect the web browser to the redirect url to my webapp server, and then the web browser will send the jwt to my webapp to identify?Does my understand is right? I am not sure whether my understand is right, I think, if the jwt send to the sever endpoint by azure b2c instead of send to the browser, the sever will unable to know the jwt is for which browser clinet, so I thing the jwt is send to the browser.

The redirect url for a webapp and the redirect uri of a native client seems have different usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A redirect URI, or reply URL, is the location that the authorization server will send the user to once the app has been successfully authorized, and granted an authorization code or access token. It is where authentication responses can be sent and received by your app. Azure AD verifies that the redirect URI sent by the web app is one of the registered redirect URIs for the app.

For native app, when authentication flow is completed, the browser tries to send the request to redirect URI, which will try to invoke the registered application on the Desktop client.

For web app, just set "https://**". For native app, you need to use [custom redirect URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) currently.

Comment: thanks for your help, does it means that, if the browser is in a webview in my app open by msal, the redirect uri is useless?

Comment: AZURE AD B2C The browser page is mis-rendered in Embedded Webviews with MSAL.net web(new versio userflow (Recommended)).  Where Can I notice azure fix this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64101050/azure-ad-b2c-the-browser-page-is-mis-rendered-in-embedded-webviews-with-msal-net/64136080#64136080