# AZURE AD B2C The browser page is mis-rendered in Embedded Webviews with MSAL.net web(new versio userflow (Recommended))

Tags: uwp, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

As the microsoft iffical said, The UWP can't use system web with aad b2c, has to use  Embedded Webviews.

But when I use MSAL.net, it offen mis-render the page, as the image below[image](in some times , the page maybe right render[image]).

And I can run the user flow and right render with my system chrome web browser .     The uwp Embedded Webviews is in old edge core(maybe this is the reason?).

what can I do? does Microsoft can solve the matter？

Answer (score 0):

B2C is supported in UWP.

Please upgrade the application to the latest SDK and for your reference, you can refer to [Universal Windows Platform (UWP) application signing in users with Azure Active Directory B2C and calling an API](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-uwp).

Comment: hi guy, the [Universal Windows Platform (UWP) application signing in users with Azure Active Directory B2C and calling an API]   is old version user flow. The azure said they will supports the old user flow no longer.    The new verson user flow is bad work in uwp, especially in the case thay the network is not very good(but chrome still can open the userfolw very fast in the same network).   please have a try the new version user flow in UWP, it some times works, some times not......orz

Comment: and, I have tried the https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-uwp, My app can use the sample's tenant and can run good(I removed the re-direct uri in my app).   And if ths sample code use my tenant, it even can't run (bacause the new version Azure B2C has to have a re-direct uri in  PublicClientApplicationBuilder.